# Discrepancy in Snippet

Tags: c++

Though the two snippets below have a slight difference in the manipulation of the find variable, still the output seems to be the same. Why so?

**First Snippet**

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {

    int number = 3,find;
    find = number << 31;
    find *= -1;
    cout << find;
    return 0;
    }
```

**Second Snippet**

```
   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
   int number = 3,find;
   find = number << 31;
   find *= 1;
   cout << find;
   return 0;
   }
```

Output for both snippets:

```
-2147483648
```

(according to Ideone: [1](http://ideone.com/pu6A1), [2](http://ideone.com/GJLL1))

Comment: what is the size of int on your machine? 32 bits? My good guess would be if you shift it 30 bits left you should get different results then.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-opera). You're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @ matcheek : Yes it`s 32, but cant figure out how the objective of the question would be met if it is changed to 30.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both your samples, assuming 32bit `int`s, you're invoking undefined behavior as pointed out in [Why does left shift operation invoke Undefined Behaviour when the left side operand has negative value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-opera)

Why? Because `number` is a signed `int`, with 32bits of storage. `(3<<31)` is not representable in that type.

Once you're in undefined behavior territory, the compiler can do as it pleases.

(You can't rely on any of the following because it is UB - this is just an observation of what your compiler appears to be doing).

In this case it looks like the compiler is doing the right shift, resulting in `0x80000000` as a binary representation. This happens to be the two's complement representation of `INT_MIN`. So the second snippet is not surprising.

Why does the first one output the same thing? In two's complement, MIN_INT would be `-2^31`. But the max value is `2^31-1`. `MIN_INT * -1` would be `2^31` (if it was representable). And guess what representation that would have? `0x80000000`. Back to where you started!