# Rounded power of 2 divider done with bitwise operations fails for some inputs

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I wrote the following function:

```
int divideBy2Power(int x, int y) { return (x >> y) + (x < 0 && x << (32 - y)); }
```

which is supposed to compute {x / (2^y)} (rounding towards zero) in an extremely efficient manner (i.e. without branching!)

In testing it works for most inputs, but for `divideBy2Power(-2, 0)` it produces `-1`.  Likewise, `x=-1, y=0` produces `0` (not `-1`). It works for bunches of other negative numbers.

I'm on a 32-bit machine and I checked that `x << 32` produces zero.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a comment: you do have a branch in there with the `&&` operator.

Comment: `-2 >> 0` is undefined, as is `x << 32`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: To be pedantic, `-2 >> 0` is merely implementation-defined.

Comment: The correct way to avoid branching is to use &, not &&, but you need to use & and shift to get the sign bit.  It gets messy, but it can be done without branching.

Comment: I'm currently trying `(!(!(x << y)) & ((x >> 31) & 1)) + (x >> y)` but that doesn't work for -2147483646[0x80000002],1  for example. It gives -1073741822[0xc0000002] but should be -1073741823[0xc0000001]

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but `&&` is a branch.

Comment: Testing that `x << 32 == 0` does **not** necessarily tell you that `x << n == 0` given `n == 32`.  The former is likely to be constant-folded to 0 at compile time.  In particular if you have an x86 CPU then shifting a 32 bit register by 32 is a nop.

Answer (score 4):

You have two sources of undefined behaviour (UB), and one of implementation-defined behaviour (IDB):

- `x << 32` is UB for all `x` (assuming you have 32-bit `int` on your platform).
- `-2 << y` is UB for all `y`.
- `-2 >> y` is IDB for all `y`.

So any behaviour you observe for `divideBy2Power(-2, 0)` is entirely down to "chance" (for lack of a better term).

I realise that this doesn't directly answer your question, but in a sense, it doesn't matter.  Invoking UB twice in one expression should be avoided at all cost; you need to find a different way to write your function.

Comment: I was seeing unexpected behavior in trying to reproduce the OPs results locally, now I know why :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the answer is obvious once you break down the expression:

New code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int divideBy2Power(int x, int y)
{
    int a = x >> y;
    int b = x < 0;
    int c = x << (32-y);
    printf("a=%d\n", a); 
    printf("b=%d\n", b); 
    printf("c=%d\n", c); 
    printf("b&&c=%d\n", (b&&c));
    return a + (b && c); 
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", divideBy2Power(-2, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Then you clearly see that b=1, c=-2 so b&&c = 1.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Assuming the Intel x86 or x86_64 instruction set, the result will always come out the same. But yes, on a different CPU it might not.

Comment: Not necessarily.  "UB" isn't just a way to express that different platforms have different hardware instructions; it's also means that the compiler is free to make assumptions when optimising.  These assumptions may in turn lead to surprising results for pathological inputs!  Here's an article about a similar (but different) case: http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you're adding the result of a binary AND comparison && (not bitwise); which will be either 0 or 1. That's nonsensical, it DOES use a branch, and has other questionable logic.

Secondly, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874464/1110687 for an explanation of why this fails with signed numbers and what exactly is undefined behavior in this case. It's about left-shifting but it applies to right-shifting also.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you meant

```
int divideBy2Power(int x, int y) { return (x >> y) + ( (x < 0)& (x << (32 - y))); }
```

Note the extra parentheses.  The order of precedence on << and >> is often not what you expect.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: Does on my system.  If it doesn't on yours, that would have to do with ( x << ( 32-y) ) being undefined.

Comment: `<<`, `>>` and `<` all have higher precedence than `&` or `&&`.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference anywhere, unless you're using a compiler that doesn't properly implement C precedence.