# template metaprogramming - g++ eats it, clang does not

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, generic-programming

Any way to get both compilers to be happy?

for this:

```
template<short value>
struct static_signbits
{
    enum { result = (!!(value & 0x8000) == !!(value & 0x4000)) ? (static_signbits<short(value << 1)>::result + 1) : 0 };
};

template<>
struct static_signbits<0>
{
    enum
    {
        result = 15
    };
};
```

clang gives me:

```
error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
        enum { result = (!!(value & 0x8000) == !!(value & 0x4000)) ? (static_signbits<short(value << 1)>::result + 1) : 0 };
                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It is apparently unhappy about the cast to the short?

Apparently, I could use constexpr instead, but I also require backward compatibility to C++98

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because clang does not support `negative << n` in constant expressions. Simply shift unsigned values instead:

```
template<short value>
struct static_signbits
{
    enum { result = (!!(value & 0x8000) == !!(value & 0x4000)) ? (static_signbits<(short)((unsigned)value << 1)>::result + 1) : 0 };
};
```

clang is correct, since left shifting a negative is  [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26474155/4955498).