# Metaprogram for size of integral type in terms of bits

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I've been getting acquainted with metaprogramming by solving various toy problems. Here's one that has me stumped: How to write a metaprogram that provides the size of an integral type argument in terms of bits. In particular, I'd like to do it without [CHAR_BIT](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) or any other magic numbers.

I started with the following non-metaprogram:

```
template <typename T>
int sizeInBits(void) {
    T flag = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (flag != 0) {
        flag <<= 1;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Converted to a metaprogram, I thought it would look like this:

```
template<typename T, int COUNT = 0, T FLAG = 1>
struct SizeInBits {
    enum {Result = SizeInBits<T, COUNT + 1, FLAG << 1 >::Result};
};

template<typename T, int COUNT>
struct SizeInBits<T, COUNT, 0> {
    enum {Result = COUNT};
};
```

However, this program fails to compile because [apparently](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31584) it is illegal to specialize on a non-type template parameter that has a template parameter type, and so I get the following error message using gcc 4.6:

```
error: type ‘T’ of template argument ‘0’ depends on a template parameter
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**:
I am essentially looking for the metaprogram equivalent of the magic numbers in `<climits>` and `<limits>`. So, for example, I would like `SizeInBits<char>::Result` to give `8` on my system, and `SizeInBits<unsigned>::Result` to give `32`.

**Note regarding validity of left bitwise shift operator on signed types**:
In the comments, there was some concern whether `FLAG << 1` is defined or not for signed types when overflow occurs. According to the C++03 standard quoted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-oper), it is defined and does what the above algos expect.

Comment: You're aware that integral promotion happens around the  `<<` operator, and that shifting a signed int past its bit lenght is undefined behavior? (I.e. I don't think your approach will work.) CHAR_BITS and sizeof aren't "magic", they're part of the standard. You should use them or type traits/numeric limits.

Comment: sizeof returns the size in chars. What you can do is estimating the size of a char and then multiply sizeof (T) with that number.

Comment: @FuleSnabel Yes, but the "estimating the size of a char" part is what I want this program to do.

Comment: @Mat Perhaps I'm mistaken, but I thought that left bit shifting was well defined when the right operand (1 in my case) was sufficiently small? And I would never use this in place of the "magic numbers" in <limits> - as I said, it is a toy problem. I've come up against a particular limitation of templates and I'm wondering if there is a way around it?

Comment: @dsmith: with signed types, the result must be representable in the target type for the shift to be well-defined. (I.e. it's undefined as soon as the 1 "drops off the high end".)

Comment: @Mat OK, let's say that we restrict the template argument to unsigned types, then.

Comment: @dsmith: it's still un-necessarily complicated compared to sizeof*CHAR_BITS.

Comment: @Mat Agreed :) Again, the point is an exploration of template metaprogramming.

Comment: @dsmith I understood that, your approach will work for char though as that is not a template type. So estimate bits of char using a meta programming approach, then multiply by sizeof(T).

Comment: @Mat: it's unnecessarily *accurate* compared with `sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT`. Unsigned integer types (except for `unsigned char` and the `uint_*` typedefs) are allowed to have padding bits, in which case the estimate with `CHAR_BIT` is only an upper bound on the width of `T`. They just never actually do have padding bits.

Comment: Which also means this function has the wrong name, btw. It should be `WidthInBits`, not `SizeInBits`. Or if it really is the size you want, not the width, then you should use `sizeof` and `CHAR_BITS`, because what you calculate in your first function is the width, not the size. You can calculate `CHAR_BIT` using this sort of trick since `unsigned char` has no padding, but you can't calculate the size of other types from their width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
template<typename T, unsigned long long flag = 1uLL>
struct bits_in {
    enum {value = 1 + bits_in<T, (unsigned long long)(T)(flag << 1)>::value};
};

template<typename T>
struct bits_in<T, 0uLL> {
    enum {value = 0};
};
```

unlike [Nicolas's version](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4f54513d1bc7a4a3f412ee0650902b37) it is simpler, produces no warnings, and [actually works correctly](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9111c60a8eb9c6c263e66ba267ff3db1).

Answer (score 2):

The type of a non-type template argument cannot depend on a template parameter of a partial specialization. The compiler will not allow the following partial specialization:

```
template <class T, T t> class X { };

// Invalid partial specialization
template <class T> class X<T, 25> { };
```

In order to solve this problem you can just use `int FLAG`:

```
#include <iostream> 

template<typename T, int COUNT = 0, int FLAG = 1>
struct SizeInBits {
    enum { 
        Result = SizeInBits<T, COUNT + 1, FLAG << 1>::Result
    };
};

template<typename T, int COUNT>
struct SizeInBits<T, COUNT, 0> {
    enum {
        Result = COUNT
    };
};

int main() {
   std::cout << SizeInBits<int, 10>::Result << std::endl;
}
```

But it seems to be you need `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT` or like this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
struct SizeInBits {
    enum { 
        Result = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT
    };
};

int main() {
   std::cout << SizeInBits<long>::Result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you've provided an explanation of the error message, but I was hoping to get at a way to design the metaprogram to avoid this limitation.

Comment: @dsmith just use `int FLAG` instead of `T FLAG`.

Comment: Yes, that allows it to compile, but then the result is for s `int` regardless of the supplied type parameter. For example, on my system `SizeInBits<char>::Result`, `SizeInBits<int>::Result` and `SizeInBits<long>::Result` all give `32` as the result. However, this points to a partial solution: restrict it to char and write a metaprogram for `CharSizeInBits<size_t COUNT = 0, char FLAG = 1>`.

Comment: Common! You already use bit-wise shift operator. What is type cannot be shifted by `int` or `unsigned` bits?

Comment: Sorry, I think perhaps my question wasn't clear enough. I'm looking for something that is, in fact, the metaprogram equivalent of the magic numbers defined in `<climits>` and `<limits>`. So, for example, I am looking for `SizeInBits<char>::Result` to give `8` on my system. I will modify the question statement to indicate this.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
template<typename T, int COUNT = 0, int FLAG = 1>
struct SizeInBits {
    enum {Result = SizeInBits<T, COUNT + 1, static_cast<T>(FLAG) << 1 >::Result};
};

template<typename T, int COUNT>
struct SizeInBits<T, COUNT, 0> {
    enum {Result = COUNT};
};
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Probably use `uintmax_t` rather than `int` for FLAG, to make this work for types bigger than `int`. Of course `uintmax_t` is theoretically less portable, it's in C++11 and C99 but not C++03.