# Bitwise left shifting unexpected result

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I found some wired problems when I tried to do left shift for 32 times. The code in the test function should print the same results of 0x0, but I got "ffffffff, 0" instead. Anybody could give a hint of what's wrong with the code? Thank you!

```
int test(int n) {
    int mask = ~0 << (32 + ~n + 1);
    int mask1 = ~0 << (32 + ~0 + 1);
    printf("%x, %x\n", mask, mask1);
    return mask;
}

int main(){
    test(0);
}
```

Comment: same with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-oper

Comment: Can you try making the int declaration an unsigned int and tell us if it will make any difference?

Answer (score 4):

In C, shifting with size greater than the type size (`int` in your case) is an **undefined behavior**

From this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-oper): Relevant quote from ISO C99 (6.5.7/4)

> The  result  of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit  positions;  vacated  bits  are  ﬁlled  with zeros.  If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type.  If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is undeﬁned**.

Comment: You mean it is still undefined if the shifting distance is the same a s the type size?

Comment: yes. if your type size is 32 then you are allowed to shift with number <= 31

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have 32-bit integers, the results of left shifting more than 31 times are undefined

From C11 `§6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators`

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
>   the result is E1 x 2E2 , reduced modulo one more than the maximum
>   value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and
>   nonnegative value, and E1 x 2E2 is representable in the result type,
>   then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.