# C++ copying integer to char[] or unsigned char[] error

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, char, unsigned

So I'm using the following code to put an integer into a char[] or an unsigned char[]

```
(unsigned???) char test[12];

test[0] = (i >> 24) & 0xFF;
test[1] = (i >> 16) & 0xFF;
test[2] = (i >> 8) & 0xFF;
test[3] = (i >> 0) & 0xFF;

int j = test[3] + (test[2] << 8) + (test[1] << 16) + (test[0] << 24);

printf("Its value is...... %d", j);
```

When I use type unsigned char and value 1000000000 it prints correctly.

When I use type char  (same value) I get 98315724 printed?

So, the question really is can anyone explain what the hell is going on??

---

Upon examining the binary for the two different numbers I still can't work out whats going on.  I thought signed was when the MSB was set to 1 to indicate a negative value (but negative char? wth?)

I'm explicitly telling the buffer what to insert into it, and how to interpret the contents, so don't see why this could be happening.

I have included binary/hex below for clarity in what I examined.

11 1010 1001 1001 1100 1010 0000 0000  // Binary for 983157248

11 1011 1001 1010 1100 1010 0000 0000  // Binary for 1000000000

3   A    9    9    C    A    0    0    // Hex for 983157248

3   B    9    A    C    A    0    0    // Hex for 1000000000

Comment: C doesn't really have "characters"; it only has small integers.  `char` is just the name for the smallest integer type, with a minimum range of `[-127, 127]` (if signed) or `[0, 255]` (if unsigned), and (unfortunately) whether or not it is signed is implementation-defined.  For this use case you *must* use `unsigned char`.

Comment: Also, to avoid triggering undefined behavior when you shift something into `int`'s sign bit, you need to do the reassembly in `uint32_t` and cast to `int` afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer by Kerrek SB please consider the following:

Computers (almost always) use something called [twos-complement notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for negative numbers, with the high bit functioning as a 'negative' indicator. Ask yourself what happens when you perform shifts on a signed type considering that the computer will handle the signed bit specially.

You may want to read [Why does left shift operation invoke Undefined Behaviour when the left side operand has negative value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-oper) right here on StackOverflow for a hint.

Comment: Interestingly I can insert values as I did previously and chuck an (ugly) cast in at the last minute i.e. unsigned char* tmp = (unsigned char*)test; then use tmp in the print.  Thanks though, this really helped =)

Comment: Right - because the cast tells the compiler how to interpret the value. The computer doesn't store a `signed` value any differently than an `unsigned` (although, *in principle*, it could). The only difference is how the computer **manipulates** the data. For example, there are different instructions to perform a signed vs. an unsigned multiplication. Both with either version, the data is stored in the same registers or just generic memory. Not in "special" `signed` or `unsigned` registers or memory.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `i & 0xFF` etc, you're creaing values in the range `[0, 256)`. But (your) `char` has a range of `[-128, +128)`, and so you cannot actually store those values sensibly (i.e. the behaviour is implementation defined and tedious to reason about).

Use `unsigned char` for unsigned values. The clue is in the name.

Comment: I think the name part doesn't apply here, since an unsigned int still won't fit even if you use unsigned chars (unless when you still use &0xff, but then you can't have all the values your int can represent).

Comment: This isn't the problem the OP is facing, although shoving `unsigned` things into `signed` boxes is not a good idea to begin with. The issue is the left shifting of a signed type.

Comment: I thought 0xFF just took the last 8 bits off the integer.  I don't think thats quite right though because memcpy(&test,&i, 4); doesn't do the shift but still has the same problem

Comment: Nik, your answer sounds pretty sensible!! When you shift a signed type do you use the same value as the MSB?? I know extending a 16bit signed value to a 32 bit you just copy the MSB.  Also, as all my values will be positive I can just use unsigned int then I guess.

Comment: wait, unsigned int makes no sense, need to type the array properly >.>

Answer (score 0):

This all has to do with `internal representation` and the way each `type` uses that `data` to interpret it. In the `internal representation` of a `signed character`, the first bit of your byte holds the sign, the others, the value. when the first bit is 1, the number is negative, the following bits then represent the `complement` of the positive value. for example:

```
unsigned char c;  // whose internal representation we will set at 1100 1011
c = (1 * 2^8) + (1 * 2^7) + (1 * 2^4) + (1 * 2^2) + (1 * 2^1);
cout << c;        // will give 203

                  // inversely:

char d = c;       // not unsigned
cout << d;        // will print -53
                  // as if the first is 1, d is negative, 
                  // and other bits complement of value its positive value
                  // 1100 1011  -> -(complement of 100 1011)
                  // the complement is an XOR +1   011 0101

                  // furthermore:

char e;           // whose internal representation we will set at 011 0101
e = (1 * 2^6) + (1 * 2^5) + (1 * 3^2) + (1 * 2^1);
cout << e;        // will print 53
```