# The output value differs from the value received as argument within the function when performing a direct operation

Tags: c

I tried to make 11..10..0 (which is binary number with consecutive 32-n zeros in small digits).

```
// Can assume that 0 <= n <= 31

int masking(int n) {
  return (~0)<<(~n+33);
}
```

However, when I put `0` in input n, I expected `0`, but I got `-1(0xffffffff)`.

Without using input,

- `(~0)<<(~0+33)` gives `0`.
- `(-1)<<32` also gives `0`.

I don't know why I got different results.

Comment: `~0` is `-1`. Shifting `-1` to the left is [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784996/11683).

Comment: you should move to unsigned int

Comment: Why do you calculate `(~n+33)` when you mean `(32-n)`?

Comment: For my assignment, only “ ! ~ & ^ | + << >>“  operators are allowed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider forcing 64 bit math. According to "C" standard, result of shifting of a variable with N bits is only defined when the number of shifts is less than the size of the variable (0..N-1)

Performing the shift on (~0) (integer, usually 32 bit), will result in undefined behavior for ~n+33 (n=0) since ~n+33 = 32, above the limit of 31.

Changing the code to use (~0L) produce the requested result masking(0) = 0

Assuming that you run on generic Linux - gcc will default to 32 bit integer, 64 bit long and 64 bit pointer.

```
include <stdio.h>

int masking(int n) {
  return (~0UL)<<(~n+33);
}

void main(void)
{
        for (int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
                printf("M(%d)=%x\n", i, masking(i)) ;
        }
}
```

Output:

```
M(0)=0
M(1)=80000000
M(2)=c0000000
M(3)=e0000000
```

Comment: For additional technical discussion, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-oper

Comment: `~0L` is still signed, so shifting it to the left is [still](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784996/11683) undefined behaviour.