# Store binary values in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, binary

I wish to store some binary values in an array in C. How it can be done and how can i access any bit of a binary number.

Plz let me know if i i am unclear in posting the doubt.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary values"?  Do you mean boolean values, i.e. flags?

Comment: Isn't all value binary internally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get bit by bit data from a integer value in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249731/how-to-get-bit-by-bit-data-from-a-integer-value-in-c)

Comment: I mean i require the binary representation of all the decimal number user enters. I need this for taking some bitwise operations

Comment: Do you want to build a bitmap, is that it?

Comment: @Ziyao Wei: internally, we are all bits :)

Comment: Why do you want to store them in binary format and not in int(s) ? You can easily create a function that creates a char* containing the binary representation of each int

Comment: @John can u explain with an example ??

Comment: you can do bitwise operations on a integer type

Comment: @Jakub Mikians: internally I'm all atoms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your values in a normal array and write a simple function that would pick proper element *and* state of its bit, something like

```
int get_bit_from_array( unsigned char *A, int element, int bit ) {
    return A[element] &  ( 1 << bit ) ;                 
}
```

or even

```
int get_bit_from_array( unsigned char *A, int bit_absolute) {
    int element = bit_absolute / 8;
    int bit = bit_absolute % 8;
    return A[element] &  ( 1 << bit ) ;                 
}
```

Comment: hmm..thats d final solution. But is there no other alternatives, because i need to make several such calls in my program

Comment: I am sure sure CPU will manage :)

Comment: Can u plz explain the above code ??

Comment: what does unsigned char *A, int bit_absolute represent above ??

Comment: You'd probably want to shift the result right by `bit` to finish it (after all you are asking for a bit value, not a masked bit).

Comment: @Chris: for boolean operations it does not matter

Comment: Yes but if I said, "get me the value of the 5th bit", and you returned 16 that would be pretty confusing (if I were expecting a 0 or 1).