# C - Get a bit from a byte

Tags: c, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get bit by bit data from a integer value in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249731/how-to-get-bit-by-bit-data-from-a-integer-value-in-c)

I have a 8-bit byte and I want to get a bit from this byte, like
    getByte(0b01001100, 3) = 1

Comment: Arrgh, so many duplicates!  Let me find one...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Firstoff, `0b` prefix is not C but a GCC extension of C.
To get the value of the bit 3 of an `uint8_t a`, you can use this expression:

```
((a >> 3)  & 0x01)
```

which would be evaluated to 1 if bit 3 is set and 0 if bit 3 is not set.

Comment: Just helping those who may be less familiar with binary, bit 3 is actually the fourth digit from the right, i.e., 1**1**110 If you wanted to get the third digit from the right, you would right shift 2, the fifth, 4, etc.

Answer (score 6):

First of all C `0b01...` doesn't have binary constants, try using hexadecimal ones. Second:

```
uint8_t byte;
printf("%d\n", byte & (1 << 2);
```

Comment: Third; off-by-one error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the & operator to mask to the bit you want and then shift it using >> as you like.