# How to get a right shifted number without actual calculation?

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation

I have the following snippet:

```
int n = 10;
int k = n>>1;
std::cout<<k;
```

This prints 5.

I want k to be the last digit in binary representation of n.
Like bin(n) = 1010
So, I want k to be 0.

I understand long methods are possible. Please suggest a one liner if possible.

**Edit:**

After going through the comments and answers, I discovered that there are various ways of doing that.

Some of them are:

```
k = n%2
k = n&1
```

Thanks to all those who answered the question. :)

Comment: you mean `n & 1`?

Comment: "This prints 5." really? what language is that?

Comment: “This prints 5.” — it doesn’t print anything. To get the low bit of a value, use `whatever & 0x01`.

Comment: `k = n & 1` or `k = n % 2`. It's basically [getting a single bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8695945/995714)

Comment: Yeah. I got the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: `n % 2` produces some trouble with negative `n`, it is a bit odd to say that the least significant bit of a negative number is negative 1

Comment: If you want k to be he last digit in binary representation of n (which is either  0 or 1), you want to know in fact if the number is even or odd ? Is it what you wanted ? if it is the case you can indeed use something line k = n %2

Comment: @Actarus> not always. Sometimes you actually want the bit value (from a bit field, from some I/O port, …). Since OP specifically tagged with bit manipulation I guess that's what he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to avoid some calculation.

```
int k = n % 10;
```

will get you the last decimal digit, as that assignment gives `k` the remainder of division by 10.

Comment: OP asked for the last digit in binary though

Comment: suggest to replace 10 with 2 and add a note that its basically the same as `n & 1`

Comment: or even just n% <desired base> just incase someone wants to work in hex or octal

Answer (score 1):

```
int main( )
{
    unsigned int val= 0x1010;
    //so you just want the least siginificant bit?
    //and assign it to another int?
    unsigned int assign= val & 0x1;

    std::cout << assign << std::endl;
    val= 0x1001;
    assign= val & 0x1;
    std::cout << assign << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

I would add that bit masking is not uncommon with c. I use ints to hold states often

```
#define STATE_MOTOR_RUNNING     0x0001
#define STATE_UPDATE_DISPLAY    0x0002
#define STATE_COUNTER_READY     0x0004
```

Then:

```
unsigned int state= STATE_COUNTER_READY;
if( state & STATE_COUNTER_READY )
{
    start_motor( );
    state|= STATE_MOTOR_RUNNING;
}
//etc...
```

Comment: What's the point of that? I mean, if it was some I/O register, or some serialized form, fine, but for normal code?

Comment: HI @spectras, I don't see much of a point, I was just answering the op's question. I added the update to try and frame it in a useful manor.