# Convert an 8 bit data to 3 bit data

Tags: c++, c, binary

PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE: C

I've a 8 bit data with only 3 bit used, for example:

0110 0001

Where 0 indicate unused bit that are always set to 0 and 1 indicate bits that change.

I want to convert this 0110 0001 8 bit to 3 bit that indicate this 3 used bits.

For example

0110 0001 --> 111

0010 0001 --> 011

0000 0000 --> 000

0100 0001 --> 101

How I can do that with minimal operations?

Comment: What is your motivation for doing so? Without other trickery, those 3 bits are still going to take at least 8 in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a couple of bitwise operations:

```
((a >> 4) & 6) | (a & 1)
```

Assuming you start from `xYYx xxxY`, where `x` is a bit you don't care about and `Y` a bit to keep:

1. left shift by 4 of `a` will result in `xYYx`, then masking with `6` (binary `110`) will make sure only the second and third bit are retained, resulting in `YY0` and preventing flipped `x` bits from messing up.
2. `a & 1` selects the LSB, resulting in `Y`.
3. the two parts, `YY0` and `Y` are combined using a `|` bitwise or, resulting in `YYY`.

Now you have the 3 bits you asked. But keep in mind that you can't address single bits, so it will still be byte-aligned as `00000YYY`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the k'th bit of n: (where n is 011000001)

```
(n & ( 1 << k )) >> k
```

(More details about that at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249731/how-to-get-bit-by-bit-data-from-a-integer-value-in-c))

so you use that to get bit 1,6 and 7 and just add those:

```
r=bit1+bit6*16+bit7*32
```