# find numbers that are the square of the sum of a partition of their digits in base 10

Tags: c

Is is possible to write a program in C which will pass any number from 1 to 13 digits and will do the possible combinations of its digits until it finds a combination of its digits whose square is the number.

These are some examples of how the sum should come out:

```
1296 = (1 + 29 + 6) = 36^2
3025 = (30 + 25) = 55^2
8281 = (8 + 2 + 81) = 91^2
998001 = (998 + 0 + 0 + 1) = 999^2
4941729 = (494 + 1729) = 2223^2
81 = (8 + 1) = 9^2
```

the digits must come out in a different way as we see in each number to create the number in the square.

I have this code:

```
int sumofdigit(long long num) {
    long long sumOfDigitGroups = 0;
    long long temp = num;

    while (temp > 0) {
        sumOfDigitGroups += temp % 10;  
        temp /= 10;

        sumOfDigitGroups += (temp % 100);  
        temp /= 100;
 
    return (num == sumOfDigitGroups * sumOfDigitGroups);
}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: So you want to find all ways of partitioning the digits of the decimal representation of a square n^2 such that the sum of each partition value is n? Good luck doing that without arrays.

Comment: do you have a code in your mind with arrays that make that think work?

Comment: Actually, I don't think you want all partitions, only those that are contiguous, which makes it a lot easier. If you have n digits, then you have n-1 places where a partition can or can not be placed, so that's 2^(n-1) possibilities. I would use a counter from 0 to 2^(n-1) - 1, then take the bits of that to work out where to partition the numbers for each iteration.

Comment: A proper and copy-pasted [mre] would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not check for all possible partitions, especially more than 2 parts.

Try and follow these steps to solve this problem without arrays or pointers:

- write a recursive function that takes a candidate number, a sum of the parts already split and the target number
- if the square of the sum of the candidate and the sum is the target number, you found a match, so print the candidate and return success
- otherwise, try all possible splits of the candidate into 2 parts and recursively check if there is a solution with this split.
- if a solution is found, print the second part and return success
- if no solution is found, return failure and let the caller try another split

Here is an implementation that finds all positive numbers of type `int` that have a partition of their digits in base 10 whose sum is their square root. It stops at 46340, that is the largest number whose square fits in the range of 32-bit integers. The code can be easily modified for larger numbers (10 to 13 digits). The time complexity slows time the search as the limit grows.

> `#include <stdio.h>`
>   
>  `int check_num(int num, int sum, int target) {`
>      `if (sum > 46340 || sum * sum > target) {`
>          `// sum is already too large: no solution`
>          `return 0;`
>      `}`
>      `if (num + sum <= 46340 && (num + sum) * (num + sum) == target) {`
>          `// we found a solution: print the first term`
>          `printf("(%d", num);`
>          `return 1;`
>      `}`
>      `for (int div = 10; num / div > 0; div *= 10) {`
>          `// try all possible splits for the next term`
>          `if (check_num(num / div, num % div + sum, target)) {`
>              `// solution found: print the next term`
>              `printf("+%d", num % div);`
>              `return 1;`
>          `}`
>      `}`
>      `return 0;`
>  `}`
>   
>  `int main(void) {`
>      `for (int i = 0; i <= 46340; i++) {`
>          `if (check_num(i * i, 0, i * i))`
>              `printf(")**2 = %d\n", i * i);`
>      `}`
>      `return 0;`
>  `}`

Output:

```
(0) = 0^2 = 0
(1) = 1^2 = 1
(8+1) = 9^2 = 81
(10+0) = 10^2 = 100
(1+29+6) = 36^2 = 1296
(20+25) = 45^2 = 2025
(30+25) = 55^2 = 3025
(6+72+4) = 82^2 = 6724
(82+8+1) = 91^2 = 8281
(98+0+1) = 99^2 = 9801
(100+0+0) = 100^2 = 10000
(5+5+225) = 235^2 = 55225
(88+209) = 297^2 = 88209
(1+361+6+1) = 369^2 = 136161
(1+369+0+0) = 370^2 = 136900
(14+364+1) = 379^2 = 143641
(17+1+396) = 414^2 = 171396
(4+3+1+649) = 657^2 = 431649
(45+5+625) = 675^2 = 455625
(494+209) = 703^2 = 494209
(5+715+36) = 756^2 = 571536
(62+726+4) = 792^2 = 627264
(826+2+81) = 909^2 = 826281
(842+72+4) = 918^2 = 842724
(8+930+2+5) = 945^2 = 893025
(929+29+6) = 964^2 = 929296
(980+10+0) = 990^2 = 980100
(982+0+8+1) = 991^2 = 982081
(998+0+0+1) = 999^2 = 998001
(1000+0+0+0) = 1000^2 = 1000000
(1+679+616) = 1296^2 = 1679616
(2+896+804) = 1702^2 = 2896804
(3+1755+24) = 1782^2 = 3175524
(494+1729) = 2223^2 = 4941729
(744+1984) = 2728^2 = 7441984
(11+3299+56) = 3366^2 = 11329956
(1+329+3316) = 3646^2 = 13293316
(1+3557+124) = 3682^2 = 13557124
(1+707+3424) = 4132^2 = 17073424
(238+0+4641) = 4879^2 = 23804641
(2+4068+836) = 4906^2 = 24068836
(2450+2500) = 4950^2 = 24502500
(25+5025+0+0) = 5050^2 = 25502500
(26+5122+0+1) = 5149^2 = 26512201
(28+0+0+5264) = 5292^2 = 28005264
(46+6762+24) = 6832^2 = 46676224
(5+1+7104+81) = 7191^2 = 51710481
(5288+1984) = 7272^2 = 52881984
(54+5+9+7321) = 7389^2 = 54597321
(56+7460+8+9) = 7533^2 = 56746089
(5+689+6849) = 7543^2 = 56896849
(5+7562+5+6+9) = 7587^2 = 57562569
(6048+1729) = 7777^2 = 60481729
(6+3+2+9+7936) = 7956^2 = 63297936
(70+8290+56) = 8416^2 = 70829056
(7+1+2+8424+9) = 8443^2 = 71284249
(76+8602+89) = 8767^2 = 76860289
(78+42+8736) = 8856^2 = 78428736
(7+93+8810+0) = 8910^2 = 79388100
(7+9+8878+44) = 8938^2 = 79887844
(8478+726+4) = 9208^2 = 84787264
(8+6+76+9225) = 9315^2 = 86769225
(8695+5+625) = 9325^2 = 86955625
(9189+1+396) = 9586^2 = 91891396
(9256+364+1) = 9621^2 = 92563641
(9+29+2+9600) = 9640^2 = 92929600
(9535+5+225) = 9765^2 = 95355225
(9802+98+0+1) = 9901^2 = 98029801
(9818+82+8+1) = 9909^2 = 98188281
(9836+6+72+4) = 9918^2 = 98366724
(9890+30+25) = 9945^2 = 98903025
(9910+20+25) = 9955^2 = 99102025
(9928+1+29+6) = 9964^2 = 99281296
(9980+0+10+0) = 9990^2 = 99800100
(9982+0+0+8+1) = 9991^2 = 99820081
(9998+0+0+0+1) = 9999^2 = 99980001
(10000+0+0+0+0) = 10000^2 = 100000000
(1+10502+1+4+4) = 10512^2 = 110502144
(1+4937+7284) = 12222^2 = 149377284
(1+6197+6529) = 12727^2 = 161976529
(2+9828+7441) = 17271^2 = 298287441
(3008+14336) = 17344^2 = 300814336
(4938+17284) = 22222^2 = 493817284
(494+21736+1) = 22231^2 = 494217361
(6+4+28+25316) = 25354^2 = 642825316
(7+5+1+5+27396) = 27414^2 = 751527396
(11+33601+56+1) = 33669^2 = 1133601561
(11+7+8+34292+9) = 34327^2 = 1178342929
(12+5+61+35364) = 35442^2 = 1256135364
(1+3+36487+3+64) = 36558^2 = 1336487364
(1+35829+1025) = 36855^2 = 1358291025
(1518+0+37444) = 38962^2 = 1518037444
(1+55+39364+0+0) = 39420^2 = 1553936400
(16+932+40201) = 41149^2 = 1693240201
(1+748+41059+6) = 41814^2 = 1748410596
(1+81+8+42544+9) = 42643^2 = 1818425449
(20+8+45616+4+9) = 45657^2 = 2084561649
(21+417+45841) = 46279^2 = 2141745841
```

Comment: I think you should explain the magic number 46340.

Comment: @anatolyg: Good point, I amended the answer to hide the code and let the OP have more fun trying.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the algorithm which generates partitions is bitmap interpretation. For example, if you have 5 elements, you have 4 spaces between elements. Each space can have 2 possible states — 0 (elements to the left and right belong to the same partition) or 1 (elements to the left and right belong to different partitions). To iterate over all possible partitionings, make a loop from binary 0000 to binary 1111 — each iteration encodes one way to partition 5 elements.

Inside the loop, calculate both the individual numbers and their sum. It's easier to work from right to left — iterate from the least significant digit to most significant one. Something like this:

```
Partitioning = ... (n-1 bits)
Num = get_digit(0)
Sum = 0
For i = 1, ..., n-1:
    If get_bit(Partitioning, i-1) == 0:
        Num = Num * 10 + get_digit(i)
    Else:
        Sum += Num
        Num = get_digit(i)
Sum += Num
```

You can find the implementation for get_bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2249731/509868).

Comment: Your approach is interesting: unlike mine, it allows for easy enumeration of all matching partitions, its time complexity is also easy to compute.  My recursive approach is faster because it is easier to incorporate simple tests to prune a substantial number of cases, while not reducing the time complexity, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to implement it in C but I would write an algorithm that :
First separate all the digits in an array like : `998001 -> [9,9,8,0,0,1]`

Then, recursively get all subsets of this array : `[9,9,8,0,0,1] -> [[9,9,8,0,0],[1]],[[9,9,8,0],[0,1]],[[9,9,8],[0,0,1]],....,[[9],[9,8,0,0,1]],...,[[9,9],[8,0],[0],[1]],....,[[9],[9],[8],[0],[0],[1]]`

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-subarrays-using-recursion/) is a code from which you could get an idea on the way to do it (it's not exactly what you want)

Then I would write a function that convert an array to a number : `[9,9,8] -> 998` and call this function for all subset, sum the numbers, square the result and if it's equal to the initial number, return true with the correct subdivision.

Comment: i want to do it without arrays and pointers

Comment: Its ok without pointers but I don't know how to do it without arrays... Why don't you want to use arrays ?

Comment: because i want to find a algorithm way to do it without pointers and arrays

Comment: You don't need arrays or pointers to implement this idea, just a bunch of nested loops and bit-fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

let's see why your code isn't working

```
sumOfDigitGroups += temp % 10;  
temp /= 10;
    
sumOfDigitGroups += (temp % 100);  
temp /= 100;
```

let's say num = `123456789`.
`temp%10` adds the last digit to sum (`sum += 9`).
`temp/10` removes the last digit from temp (`temp = 12345678`).
`temp%100` adds the new last two digits to the sum (`sum += 78`).
and then `temp/100` removes the last two digits from temp (`temp = 123456`).
you can check this by printing the values of temp and sum after value change.

then all 4 operations repeat until temp has no digits left. (this will happen if the return statement was outside the while loop, since it is within, it will only check 3 digits and return true or false)

if we keep going like this, you'll see your code partitions the number in a pattern like this:
9 + 78 + 6 + 45 + 3 + 12 (or 12 + 3 + 45 + 6 + 78 + 9). this is why, it works for the first 2 cases. because this pattern fits their possible solution.
81 => 8 + 1.
1296 => 1 + 29 + 6.

but you are only checking one type of combination of digits. you have to check every possible combination. eg. for 1296, check 12 + 96 as well. check 1 + 296 as well. check 1 + 2 + 9 + 6 as well until a solution is found. find a way to check every possible combination.